# Remove Substring according to specific pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, wildcard

I need to remove in a SQL Server database a substring according to a pattern:

Before: `Winter_QZ6P91712017_115BPM`

After: `Winter_115BPM`

Or

Before: `cpx_Note In My Calendar_QZ6P91707044`

After: `cpx_Note In My Calendar`

Basically delete the substring that has pattern **_ + 12 chars**.

I've tried `PatIndex('_\S{12}', myCol)` to get the index of the substring but it doesn't match anything.

Comment: what version of SQL server

Comment: version 14.0.2037 @DhruvJoshi

Comment: `PATINDEX` is not regex, not sure why you thought it would be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

late to the party, but you could also use latest STRING_SPLIT function to explode the string by underscores and count length of each segment between underscores. If the length is >=12, these sections must be replaced from original string via replace function recursively.

```
drop table if exists Tbl;
drop table if exists #temptable;
create table Tbl (input nvarchar(max));
insert into Tbl VALUES
    ('Winter_QZ6P91712017_115BPM'),
    ('cpx_Note In My Calendar_QZ6P91707044'),
    ('stuff_asdasd_QZ6P91712017'),
    ('stuff_asdasd_QZ6P91712017_stuff_asdasd_QZ6P91712017'),
    ('stuff_asdasd_QZ6P917120117_stuff_asdasd_QZ6P91712017');


select 
    input, value as replacethisstring,
    rn = row_number() over (partition by input order by (select 1))
    into #temptable
from 
    (
        select 
            input,value as hyphensplit 
        from Tbl 
            cross apply string_split(input,'_')
    )T cross apply string_split(hyphensplit,' ')
where len(value)>=12

; with cte as (
select input, inputtrans= replace(input,replacethisstring,''), level=1 from #temptable where rn=1
union all
select T.input,inputtrans=replace(cte.inputtrans,T.replacethisstring,''),level=level+1 
from cte inner join #temptable T on T.input=cte.input and rn=level+1
--where level=rn 
)
select input, inputtrans 
from (
select *, rn=row_number() over (partition by input order by level desc) from cte
) T where rn=1
```

sample output
[image]

Comment: `string_split` does not make any guarantee about the order in which sub strings are returned. `order by (select 1)` does not guarantee anything, unfortunately.

Comment: @SalmanA agree and the ordering does not impact the solution. It does not matter in what order we make replacements on string. Example - `REPLACE(REPLACE(string, 'A',''),'B','')` is same as `REPLACE(REPLACE(string, 'B',''),'A','')`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you mean underscore followed by 12 characters that are not underscores you can use this pattern:

```sql
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[_][^_][^_][^_][^_][^_][^_][^_][^_][^_][^_][^_][^_]%', str) > 0
         THEN STUFF(str, PATINDEX('%[_][^_][^_][^_][^_][^_][^_][^_][^_][^_][^_][^_][^_]%', str), 13, '')
         ELSE str
    END
FROM (VALUES
    ('Winter_QZ6P91712017_115BPM'),
    ('Winter_115BPM_QZ6P91712017')
) AS tests(str)
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't support Regex. Considering, however, you just want to remove the first `'_'` and the 12 characters afterwards, you could use `CHARINDEX` to find the location of said underscore, and then `STUFF` to remove the 13 characters:

```sql
SELECT V.YourString,
       STUFF(V.YourString, CHARINDEX('_',V.YourString),13,'') AS NewString
FROM (VALUES('Winter_QZ6P91712017_115BPM'))V(YourString);
```

Comment: unfortunately is not enough, I need that the pattern is completely matched. 
For instance: i may have 'stuff_asdasd_QZ6P91712017' and it will return 'stuff91712017'

Comment: Then your question is incomplete, @mferre . `'stuff_asdasd_QZ6P91712017'` with "delete all the substring that has pattern _ + 12 chars" is `'stuff1712017'` not `'stuff91712017'`.